# How to fix Fullscreen Overlay Styles & Effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I am trying to make the overlay effect disappear after a menu link in the navigation has been clicked on and make the button which triggered this effect go back to its original state.

**This is what it does** 
http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/#

As you noticed after opening the overlay it doesnt disappear after pressing a link how can this be achieved?

**I attempted this code**

```
 $('#overlay-menu ul li a').click(function(){
  $("#overlay").slideUp("fast");
  $(".button_container").removeClass("active");

});

 $('.button_container').click(function(event){
  $("#overlay").slideDown("fast");
  $(".button_container").removeClass("active");

});
```

That does work kind of but the button has the incorrect action applied to it, It can only works when it has the 'X' icon instead of the menu icon.

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/HT9Bx/566/

Sorry the actual links dont show for some reason but if you hover over the centre you can see the cursor is activated. So how can I make it work open and close the overlay with the correct icons being displayed in Menu button.

Hope this made sense, found it pretty hard to explain. But if you fiddle around with the jsfiddle you'll understand just assume th links are at the centre of the overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have three clicks event for the same element.
Uncomment the `$(".button_container").removeClass("active");`

```
$('#overlay-menu ul li a').click(function(){
  $("#overlay").slideUp("fast");
  //$(".button_container").removeClass("active");
});

$('.button_container').click(function(event){
  $("#overlay").slideDown("fast");
  //$(".button_container").removeClass("active");
});

$('#toggle').click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
 $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HT9Bx/569/)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but and it did quite solve the question but as ou can see why does 'X' still appear even after clicking on a link?

Comment: Tested that and it does work only on the first few go after it just messes up.

Comment: Can you tell me how you did it please

Comment: I added the $('#overlay').removeClass('open');  under #overlay-menu click event